# RSpec 'change' can't spot a difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I've been struggling with change tests for awhile now. I got this test:

```
let(:office)   { create(:office) }

...

it "toggles products free attribute", :focus do
  expect do
    patch :toggle_free, product_ids: [office.id]
  end.to change(office, :free).to(1)
end
```

I know exactly that the code works. I print #free in console before and after it, but #change doesn't catch them. What am I doing wrong? I've been using brackets notation too with no success. I'm pretty sure that the answer is pretty simple, but I can't solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably need to reload `office`, try adding a `office.reload` after the patch and before the end.

Comment: Damn, as I said, that simple. :) Thanks! I was pretty sure I tried this as I was using rails scaffold examples.

Comment: You can write an answer and I'll mark it as useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload `office`, add a `office.reload` after the `patch` and before the `end`, this is so that your object notices the change in the database and gets updated.